# sql invalid identifier, using alias

Tags: sql, oracle, nested

```
select student.ID, course_id
from (
  select student.ID, course_id
  from student,takes 
  where student.id = takes.id
  group by student.ID,course_id
  having count(student.ID) >1
  )
group by student.id
having count(*)>2
```

I am new to sql, and struggling with the nested subqueries. 
This is what I did, trying to find who have retaken at least 3 courses at least once. it didn't work. and I know it seems weird too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full disclosure: I haven't tested this for syntax errors, but I did see two main issues with your code.
A: You need to give an alias to your subquery
B: You need to use the variable names within your subquery along with that new alias in your outer query  (note that I've assigned an alias of "student_id" for student.id in your inner query)

```
select 
    retakes.student_id,
    retakes.course_id
from 
(
    select 
        student.ID student_id,
        course_id
    from student,takes 
    where student.id = takes.id
    group by student.ID, course_id
    having count(*) >1
) retakes
group by retakes.student_id
having count(*)>2
```

It would be helpful if you included the error that you're getting with your original post (or with any subsequent answers).

Comment: Thanks! I realize the problem is that the student id is invisible, but after I give the subquery alias, it still shows error. SQL Error: ORA-00904: "STUDENT_ID": invalid identifier

Comment: Break down and isolate the problem: does the inner query alone return values or an error? I think the only issue here is that `count(student_id)` should be replaced with `count(*)`

Comment: I have tested the inner query and it works fine. After I change it to count(*),both retakes and student.id are invalid identifiers now..

Comment: ^ Nick is on to it here.  Run the subquery alone and see if it works alright.  My guess is that you might have forgot to alias student.id to "student_id" in the inner query.   @Nick.McDermaid: I'll edit to count(*), but count(student_id) should work just the same here.

Comment: It should but I don't think column `student_id` exists. We don't know though - there is no table DDL. And I suspect if the OP took the time to post it he might note that he has some column names incorrect.

Comment: there is no student_id... I am so confused with the nested queries

Comment: It's no big deal, as it was confusing, but the HAVING will pick up on the alias student_id that I've assigned to student.ID.  @RhumB, I just popped my query into jfiddle and there's no syntax error there.  Try copy and pasting.

Comment: It is working! Thank you so much! May I ask why I should use student_id as alias?

Comment: You don't -have- to use student_id as an alias, but if you did not, your outer query's SELECT statement would read "SELECT retakes.id..." and "id" is not a terribly descriptive name.  You just have to remember that you need to reference the column names as they appear if you had run the inner query on its own.

Comment: I see. It makes sense now. Thanks!